# How is Aaron is the oldest when Moses was the first born?

Tags: exodus

How is it that Aaron is Moses oldest brother when Moses was the first born male.

Comment: In all the sources I’ve seen, Aaron is older than Moses and their sister Miriam is older than both of them. What is your source for the view that Moses was the first-born?

Comment: Who is making these claims?

Comment: Aaron, not Aron. This needs a reference showing where it is stated or implied that Moses was firstborn. @Marc, it is generally thought that they were biological brothers.

Answer (score 1):

They were of similar age but Aaron must have been around 3 years older.

> And Moses was eighty years old, and Aaron eighty-three, when they spoke to Pharao.

[Exodus 7:7](http://biblehub.com/exodus/7-7.htm)